# How to make index=False or get rid of first column while using MultiIndex and to_excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, xlsxwriter

Here is the code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

tuples = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]

pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)

print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1')
```

The excel output created: [image]

Now how to get rid of first column.

Even if I don't mention index=['A', 'B', 'C'] or names=['first', 'second']

It'll by default create index=[0, 1, 2]

So how to get rid of that first column while creating the excel.

Comment: I'm confused. The answer is in your title: `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1', index=False)`

Comment: @PaulH Currently, `index=False` is not yet implemented for Multiindex columns. It will throw error.

Comment: @meW Exactly. So now there is no way to get rid of that column ?

Comment: One possible way is to set the index by first column but only drawback is that `bar, one` will be written in cell `3A` of sheet as `'bar', 'one'`. You can improve on this by making it multilabel. Use `df = df.set_index(('bar', 'one'))` before `writer` to get it done.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 5 lines fix -

Original code -

```
tuples = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), columns=index)
```

New 5 lines to be added after above code -

```
# Setting first column as index
df = df.set_index(('bar', 'one'))

# Removing 'bar', 'one' frm index name
df.index.name = ''

# Setting new columns Multiindex
tuples = [('', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]
index_new = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['bar', 'one'])
df.columns = index_new
```

Later write to excel as you are doing -

```
# Writing to excel file keeping index
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1')
```

[image: img]

*Note - There's just a small drawback that cell `A1` and `B1` are not merged.*

Comment: Just the solution I have been seeking for several days now. This solution works beautifully to remove the default index column before writing multi-index Excel docs.

Comment: @Jerry Glad, it helped! :)

Comment: Thanks this really worked great.  Too bad we can't get that empty row (#3) to be removed for saving it to excel.

Answer (score 0):

@meW thanks for your solution.
I was able to make this work with pivot tables. I thought this may help others as well.

I have flattened the column headings to a single row in the first code snippet.

I was also able to make it work with multiple column heading rows, however, I noticed the Columns name value (ie. Fee)  cannot be displayed, instead a blank row in the columns headers exists and also exist when saving it to_excel.

```
students = pd.DataFrame({'Student Names' : ['Jenny', 'Singh', 'Charles', 'Richard', 'Veena'],
                   'Category' : ['Online', 'Offline', 'Offline', 'Offline', 'Online'],
                   'Gender' : ['Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female'],
                  'Courses': ['Java', 'Spark', 'PySpark','Hadoop','C'],
                   'Fee': [15000, 17000, 27000, 29000, 12000],
                   'Discount': [1100, 800, 1000, 1600, 600]})
```

**Flatten Column Headings to single row**

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(students, index=['Gender','Courses'], columns=['Fee'], values=['Discount','Category'], aggfunc = {'Discount':'mean','Category':'count'}, fill_value = 0 )
pv.columns = pd.Index( [ '_'.join([str(c) for c in c_list]) for c_list in pv.columns.values ] )
pv = pv.reset_index()
first_column = pv.columns[0]
pv=pv.set_index(first_column)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pv.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1')
writer.save()
```

[image]

**Multi Column Headings**
A blank 3rd row remains.

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(students, index=['Gender','Courses'], columns=['Fee'], values=['Discount','Category'], aggfunc = {'Discount':'mean','Category':'count'}, fill_value = 0 )
pv = pv.reset_index()
first_column = pv.columns[0]
pv=pv.set_index(first_column)
pv.index.name=''
index_new = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pv.columns.values, names=first_column)
pv.columns = index_new
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pv.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1')
writer.save()
```

[image]

Update: For flattening it's made a bit easier now.

```
p = pd.pivot_table(students, index=['Gender','Courses'], columns=['Fee'], values=['Discount','Category'], aggfunc = {'Discount':'mean','Category':'count'}, fill_value = 0 )
p.columns = [ '_'.join([str(k) for k in cols]) for cols in p.columns.to_flat_index() ]
p=p.reset_index()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
p.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test2',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Thanks - this really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Telling `xlsxwriter` to start in column `-1` is a good and simple workaround:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=-1)
```